# Updating select options with jQuery doesn't show new options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Struggling for two days with update cascading select options, and didn't find any solution that suits me.

So, here is my code :

```
    function getCity(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "getCity.php",
data:'state_id='+val,
success: function(data){

    let dropdown = $('#city-list');
    dropdown.empty();

    var cities = data;
    $.each(cities, function (key,entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.lga_name));
    dropdown.trigger('change', true);
    });


}
});
}
```

With last line `dropdown.trigger('change', true);` I am getting updated in `<select class="selectpicker"></select>` only first (selected) option.
Actually , new options are loaded, what I found when inspect the page, but can not get them visible. I think that somewhere is the conflict between jQuery and bootstrap-select.min.js

I appreciate any guidelines.

Comment: Probably not related to your main issue, but your `.trigger()` code isn't using [the second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) correctly.

Comment: I am getting the same result with `trigger('change')` . I wondering if there is an option to force the visibility of the new options. Thx anyway.

Comment: As I said, the `.trigger()` code was not related to your issue. It's just a misuse of the second argument.

Comment: Anytime you modify the DOM, the page is automatically updated. There is no need to force visibility unless you are using CSS to hide elements.

Comment: Thank's Scott. This code is working properly if I remove class from select, what implies to conflict between class and this function. But I have no enough experience in javascript to locate the issue.

Comment: Well, you haven't posted or mentioned anything about CSS, but apparently, that is where the problem is.

Comment: In order for us to assist you, please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Based on these comments and what you said, it sounds like the problem may be styling related.